# Cannot connect to external mysql database using openshift node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift, node-mysql

I created a Node.js application on Openshift and the server does work.

However, I have a mysql databse on another server that I would like to connect. I already gave  permissions for remote mysql access to the openshift IP address.

I keep receiving this error:

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'ipaddress' (using password: YES)
```

This exact code works on my localhost connecting to the remote database server:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'host',
          port     : 'port',
          user     : 'user',
          password : 'pass',
          database : 'db'
        });

        connection.connect();
        var b;
        console.log(query);
        connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
           b = rows;
           console.log(b);
           console.log(rows);
           result(b);
        });
```

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: can you manually connect to your external database directly from the gear using `mysql`

Comment: You can ssh into your gear with `rhc ssh <yourappname>` and run 'mysql' with the appropriate options to connect to a remote database

Comment: It gives me error 2003 (HY000) (110)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you ssh into your OPenShift gear and then try to telnet to host and port of your mysql instance

```
telnet host port
```

If you can not connect then you have not actually exposed your MySQL instance so that your node.js application on OPenShift can see it.

Just as a side note, exposing your database to the outside world like that is pretty risky. Is there some reason why you can't use the MySQL instance on OpenShift?

Comment: I know it has security issues but is for test purpose.
By ssh it gives me access denied from openshift gear. However i can connect from my localhost server to the remote database. That's what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift Online does not provide a static IP address for your application, so external IP-based whitelists may not work well for granting remote access (from an OpenShift-hosted instance, to an external DB).

Is it possible to add your openshift gear's domain name to your external MySQL db's connection whitelist instead?